# Select elements where attribute is non-empty

Tags: css, css-selectors

Suppose I have the following:

```
<div data-pid="">Unknown</div>
<div data-pid="123">Known 123</div>
```

Is there a way in CSS to select only elements where the `data-pid` attribute is non-empty?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This works, if you don't mind doing things slightly backwards and you need it to work in browsers that don't support `:not`:

```
div[data-pid] {
    color: green;
}

div[data-pid=""] {
    color: inherit;
}
```

That will make all the `div`s with non-empty `data-pid`s green.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuSRM/

Comment: Accepting this answer because of being six seconds faster than alex. Although I don't know if `inherit` is the best thing to use for browser support :p

Answer (score 45):

Looks ugly, but something like this should do it:

```
[data-pid]:not([data-pid=""])
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8fVs7/)

With a little Javascript you could also add classes, if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: Fair enough. So there's no single attribute selector?

Comment: @Kolink I don't see anything in http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

Answer (score 8):

```
/* Normal styles */
[data-pid] {}

/* Differences */
[data-pid=""] {}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WWZeH/).

This will have much better browser support. Instead of selecting the ones you want, style all of them and then place the differences in the second selector.

Answer (score 1):

Directly answering the OP's notes: `div[data-pid]:not([data-pid=""]) { ... }` will work cleanly as [@kapa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16429295/1260448) shared.

But thoroughly addressing the title question, and addressing another common use case:

HTML:

```
<a>Should NOT have cursor pointer. NOT linkable.</a>
<a href>Should NOT have cursor pointer. NOT linkable.</a>
<a href="">Should NOT have cursor pointer. NOT linkable.</a>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">SHOULD have cursor pointer.</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:not([href]), /* Accounts for <a> */
a[href=""] /* Accounts for <a href> and <a href=""> */
{
  cursor: default;
}
```

[MDN Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) is a great resource for a ton of other similar attribute selectors when concerned with their values.