# CSS attribute selector for existing but non-empty attributes

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector that applies to *non-empty* attributes? Using `:not([Data-Attribute=''])` matches if the attribute is *non-existing*, too.

I'm looking for something like `[Data-Attribute!='']`.

Comment: It wouldn't be similar to `[Data-Attribute!='']` if you're talking about the jQuery selector, because the jQuery selector is equivalent to `:not([Data-Attribute=''])` and does match if the attribute is not specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select elements where attribute is non-empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429220/select-elements-where-attribute-is-non-empty)

Answer (score 281, accepted):

try this

```
<style>
    [Data-Attribute]:not([Data-Attribute=""])
    {
        background-color: Red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I've seen a better (or different) solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429220/select-elements-where-attribute-is-non-empty

Comment: @Sven The only solution on that link that answers this question (select a specific data attribute that is not empty) is identical to this answer.

Comment: Yup, the solution provided here targets what he needs, the one in the link above requires counter-styling.

Comment: This solution affects unexpected elements (if matching attr `title`).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a sass/scss solution:

```
.selector {
  @include attr-isset('attribute-name') {
    ...styles
  }
}
```

you may use this mixin:

```
/**
 * Requires
 */
@use "sass:meta";

/**
 * Select current scope only if a given attribute is set
 * @param {string} $attribute - Attribute name, default: 'class'
 * @param {boolean} $empty - Allow empty attribute
 * @param {string} $error - Error message prefix
 * @output Wraps given content styles to apply only if the current scope element has the given attribute
 */
@mixin attr-isset($attribute: 'class', $empty: false, $error: 'attr-isset::') {
  @if meta.content-exists() != true {
    @error '#{$error}@content is required';
  }
  @if $empty {
    &[#{$attribute}] {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    &[#{$attribute}]:not([#{$attribute}='']) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

## for style false support

`[{ font: ["sofia", "slabo", "roboto", "inconsolata", "ubuntu", false] }]`

```
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item:not([data-value])::before {
content: "default";
font-family: none !important;}

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label:not([data-value])::before {
content: "default";}
```