# How to create css selector that target element with attr that not empty

Tags: css, selector

It's easy to target `button#1` with `button[data-state]` but how can I target the other two with another one selector.

```
<button id=1 class=notify data-state> some text </button>
<button id=2 class=notify data-state="downloading"> some text </button>
<button id=3 class=notify data-state="render"> some text </button>
```

I am looking for a selector that can target attribute that is not empty.
How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS attribute selector for non-empty attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248915/css-attribute-selector-for-non-empty-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
button[data-state]:not([data-state=""]) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id=1 class=notify data-state> some text </button>
<button id=2 class=notify data-state="downloading"> some text </button>
<button id=3 class=notify data-state="render"> some text </button>
```