# How can I style ng-reflect-model in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

This is the part of my code when I inspect it:

```
<input disabled="" required="" type="text" ng-reflect-name="id" ng-reflect-model="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine">
```

The `ng-reflect-model` is dynamically filled, upon other action:

```
<input disabled="" required="" type="text" ng-reflect-name="id" ng-reflect-model="A1" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine">
```

I need to style this with CSS when the `ng-reflect-model` is `:empty` and when it is `:not(:empty)`

This works:

```
input[ng-reflect-model]:empty {
//CSS STYLES
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
input:not([ng-reflect-model]:empty), input[ng-reflect-model]:not(:empty) {
//CSS STYLES
}
```

What would be a work-around?

Thanks.

Comment: `input:empty` means that the `input` has no child elements. Is that what you intended? Maybe you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429220/select-elements-where-attribute-is-non-empty

Comment: Not really.. doesn't help.

Comment: Here's a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/55k2j4L1/

Comment: As show [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8639309/1737263), you can't do that.

Comment: @AlexK, I can do it with javascript easily mate, but thanks. I wanted to see if there is any CSS hack for this. Please post this as a solution and I'll accept it. Thanks.